# Calculation based on dependent dropdown using two sources

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a tool that will take a QTY someone has entered and the value for a qty, and then multiply those two. The value for those types (aka the sizes) are housed in tables on separate sheets. I need help creating the formula in ColG on the input sheet. For sake of ease I haven't created the data validation for ColD and ColE but they will be there.

For clarity, colE on the input sheet lists out numbers, but for all intents and purposes, those are just labels. Those could just as easily be Large, Medium, Small, Blue, Green, whatever.

Here is an example of the input sheet:
[image]

Here is data source a - Please note: Cols A:C are one table and E:J are another table, with the header row populated by A2:A:
[image]

Here is source b: Cols A:B are one table and D:I in another table, with the header row populated by A2:A
[image]

Here is a link to the sample document - I'd absolutely love it if someone can walk me through the formula that they use. I'm not sure what formulas to even utilize here and would love to watch some tutorials after receiving help, so I can hopefully do this myself in the future.

EDIT: I have updated the sheet so that @Twilight formula is now in Input G2 & G3. Trying to get an array formula in G1

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ex5kMzHIvp6tQfsC1HIw4Vq7f1uc1Ovr9IfJQHXBw5k/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: Can you please clarify how you get the value `160.0`? Shouldn't the `Type A` row must correspond to the `Type A` column in Source B which is 285.6?

Comment: On the input sheet - I've selected Type B and 10x8 size. That corresponds to H2. the data sources have two tables with each sheet. Using soucre b as the example - Col G,H,I pull automatically from Col A2:A. Whenever a new type is added, a new column is added to that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A2,"[0-9]"),INDIRECT("'Source A'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B2,'Source A'!E:E,0),MATCH(A2,'Source A'!$1:$1,0),4)),INDIRECT("'Source B'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B2,'Source B'!F:F,0),MATCH(A2,'Source B'!$1:$1,0),4)))*C2
```

The formula above will determine the specific **Type (Column A)** and **Size (Column B**) that you entered from the input sheet and look for its corresponding values either in **Source A** or **Source B** then multiplying that value to the **QTY**.

**Please note** **that the header you have in Source A or B should match exactly with the Col A input sheet.**

**Result:**
[image]

Reference:

- [MATCH function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)
- [INDIRECT Function](https://www.liveflow.io/product-guides/indirect)
- [ADDRESS Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)

Comment: thank you so much. this is definitely doing what I want. Fields A & B will be validated from ranges to alleviate the problem that you honed in on with formatting. Would you have an idea of what i'm doing wrong when converting this to an array?




`={"Output";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"[0-9]"),INDIRECT("'Source A'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B2:B,'Source A'!E:E,0),MATCH(A2:A,'Source A'!$1:$1,0),4)),INDIRECT("'Source B'!"&ADDRESS(MATCH(B2:B,'Source B'!F:F,0),MATCH(A2:A,'Source B'!$1:$1,0),4)))*C2:C)}`

Comment: I also tried to substitute in a named range that combines all the sizes from A with all the sizes from B. that broke as well. If you could suggest a tweak, i'm all ears. cheers

Comment: Sorry I am unable to formulate it using arrayformula it keeps returning only the first result across the whole data. This is the formula I've come up with however you need to drag it below across your data

Comment: roger that and thanks. i'll leave it open in case someone else has any idea.

Comment: @Martín perhaps you might know of some way to get this into an array formula? I know indirect doesn't work but not sure how to adjust it.